# Anyone got 95812 HRZ W712PK regulator datasheet?

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, pwm

I would like to know about 95812 HRZ W712PK's datasheet or pinout diagram. I googled the datasheet but it only has one page and doesn't include pinout diagram. so guys please help ...[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to request it from the manufacturing. Googling this partnumber gives me the `ISL95812` chip. Which in turn led me to [the website of the product](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/products/power-management/computing-power-vrm-imvp/multiphase-controllers/device/ISL95812.html#overviewInfo).
There you can find the short datasheet, probably the one you found. In the top right corner it says:

> To request the full datasheet, please visit www.intersil.com/products/isl95812

On the site you can click on `Request Full Datasheet` (top right, beneath the banner)

*EDIT:*
*Some extra information on the part string:*

**What does `95812 HRZ W712PK` mean?**

- `95812` is the partnumber, which leads to `ISL95812`
- `HRZ` will probably note the specific configuration of the `ISL95812`
  (like what kind of package/footprint/temperature range)
- `W712PK` holds the information of when it is made. This particular
  chip is most likely made in week 7 of the year 2012

Comment: I mailed the manufactured and it's doesn't reply me back yet. Can you recommend a similar chip like ISL95812 ???

Comment: @HtetLwinKyaw wait a couple of days, otherwise start looking on your distributor's website after regulators with that kind of package